# find count of word in sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find number of times word "dear" is used in following sentence using Regex. Any ideas? so in this example i should get 4

> Hello DEAR Friend, This is a string that contains repeititons of word dear; so my dear if you can keep count of word dear used, it will be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Regex reg = new Regex("\\bdear\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
int count = reg.Matches(input).Count;
```

Or am I missing something in your question ?

Comment: I'm almost embarrassed to say that, while I figured there would be some simple option like that, the first thing I tried was "[Dd][Ee][Aa][Rr]"...

Comment: That doesn't discount "dearest"

Comment: @driis you are missing nothing, was just too lazy to google it :)

Comment: Well, actually this solution will count also "dear" occurrence into other words... you should use "\\bdear\\b"

Comment: Edit: I Updated regex with a version that doesn't match `dear` within words.

Comment: is there anyway of getting the index of each occurance of that word in sentence too?

Comment: @driis: that's wrong because `[^\w]` is not a zero-length matching (infact the third match is equal to `"dear;"`). Use `\b` instead --> [LINK](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: @driis: as digEmAll says, you should use `\b` rather than `\W`. With `\W`, it won't match "dear" at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: This doesn't account for sentences beginning or ending with the target word. Also, as others have noticed, `[^\w]` will include an extra character at the beginning and end of each match. What you want is `@"\bdear\b"`.

Comment: Thanks for comments, updated answer again with correct Regex.

Answer (score 1):

As you've phrased the question, you don't need to use regex for this. You should usually use string manipulation instead of regex when you can; in this case, you only need it if your target (`dear` in your example) is going to be an entire class of valid choices.

Unless that's the case, I suggest string manipulation instead. One possibility:

```
int count = source.ToLower().Split("dear").Length - 1;
```

I'm open to a more efficient version without having to use `ToLower()`, but for most purposes I wouldn't worry about that. It should still be faster than regex.

Comment: This solution will count also `"dearest"`

Comment: Why the -1?  In order to eliminate "dearest"?  That will work for this particular sentence, but not in the general case.

Comment: @imak: If all you're using it for is case insensitivity, regex is more than you need. It's also *usually* slower than string manipulation, especially for simple tasks. In your specific case, I can't say for certain that it's less efficient, since that would take some testing; but consider also the fact that the above is faster to write, easier to read, and communicates the intent more clearly.

Comment: @digEmAll: Correct. This wasn't disallowed in the question, so I considered it acceptable.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: The `- 1` is because the length will always be 1 longer than the count of the separator. For example, `"this is a test".Split("dear").Length` = 1, because the separator wasn't found, and the string was left whole. `"this is a dear test".Split("dear").Length` = 2, because it was broken into two chunks.

Comment: @Justin: Thanks. I was thinking of word counts and completely forgot that `Split` is basically counting things between words. Call it brain freeze...it's cold here today.